# Rotate BarButtonItem by 45 degrees (animated)

Tags: ios, animation, rotation, uibarbuttonitem

looks like animations are not my speciality :/

In my navigation bar I have a custom BarButtonItem, a plus, to add stuff to the list. I wanted to rotate the plus by 45 degrees so it becomes a X when it was pressed and works as a cancel button then.

I added a button as custom view to the BarButtonItem by doing this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var addQuestionaryButton: UIBarButtonItem!
{
    didSet {
        let icon = UIImage(named: "add")
        let iconSize = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: icon!.size)
        let iconButton = UIButton(frame: iconSize)
        iconButton.setBackgroundImage(icon, for: .normal)
        addQuestionaryButton.customView = iconButton
        iconButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(QuestionaryListViewController.addClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine.
Now if the button is pressed I do the following:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:{
            self.addQuestionaryButton.customView!.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_4))
        })
```

I can see the button starting to rotate but somehow it gets totally deformed. See the pictures for that:

Before:

[image: Normal state, before it is pressed]

After:

[image]

I don't understand why this happens. 
How do I correctly animate the BarButtonItem?

Thanks in advance.

Greetings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know why this is happening(my guess is when doing the transform, the frame of the customView will be messed up) but found a solution.
Just put the button into another UIView and then set this UIView as the customView of the UIBarButtonItem.

When doing the animation, don't rotate the UIView, rotate the button.

Reminder: Don't forget to set the frame of this UIView.

Sample code in Objective C:
Init:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton* itemButton;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //button init
    self.itemButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [self.itemButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.itemButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);

    //container for the button
    UIView* btnContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];
    btnContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [btnContainer addSubview:self.itemButton];
    //set the container as customView of the UIBarButtonItem
    UIBarButtonItem* applyButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnContainer];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = applyButton;
}
```

Code to trigger the rotation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.itemButton.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.itemButton.transform, M_PI_4);
}];
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response, I had a busy weekend.
I will try that this evening and will let you know.

Thanks.

Comment: Very well, thank you very much, that worked perfectly.
Still wondering why it didn't work in the first place but now it's good!